# the data do not display in my view

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, foreach

**Undefined variable: data in my view**

This is a simple display data in the input.

So, why this input isn't display my query result at it?

**my view**

```
<input type="text" name="sitename" value="<?php echo $data['sitename']; ?>"><br>
```

**model**

```
public function getData()
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT 1";

    if (!$sqli  = mysqli_query($this->cxn->connect(),$query))
    {
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Request");
    }
    else
    {
        $num = mysqli_num_rows($sqli);

        while ($num > 0) 
        {
            $data = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli);
            $num--;
        }

        return $data;   
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message? Where do you call `getData`? Quotes are for strings, backticks are for tables/columns.

Comment: If the query returns 0 rows, you never set `$data`.

Comment: is there a `$data=getData();` or equivalent, some where?

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop when the query has `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @Dagon yes there is

Comment: @Barmar so how should i display my data

Comment: @ziko0 Initialilze the variable first.

Comment: @Barmar actually i already did that at my submiting class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: i'm sorry thanks for your note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because a variable is declared somewhere, doesn't mean it is available everywhere. All variables have `scope` in which they are accessible. See this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for more information on scope.

You need to pass the `$data` variable into your view. I image you're using some sort of MVC framework since you have a model and a view. If this is the case you can lookup how to pass variables into views in that specific framework. The basic structure of your controller method might look something like this:

```
//sudo code - not specific to an actual framework
public function controller_method() 
{
  $data = $model->getData();
  $this->template->set('data',$data);
  $this->template->load('view');
}
```

Just search how to do that in your specific framework. Hope that helps!

**EDIT**
Base on your comment it looks like you're setting data *after* you load the view. You need to swap the order and call `$display = new Display("main"); $data = $display->getData();` *before* you `include'../model/display.php';`

Comment: I think he's getting the error from the `return $data` statement inside the `getData()` function, not the caller.

Comment: He is setting $data in the if statement.

Comment: @ziko0: where do you call `getData()`? and where do you load your view?

Comment: @MrMadsen        else{ try { include '../model/cone.php'; include'../model/display.php'; $display = new Display("main"); $data = $display->getData(); } catch (Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); } }

Comment: @MrMadsen yes thank you very much your editing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If the query returns 0 rows, your `while()` loop will never execute, so it won't set `$data`.

Since you're only returning 1 row from the query, you don't need a loop, you can just use an `if`. Then you can return `$data` only when it succeeds.

```
public function getData()
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $this->tablename ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT 1";

    if (!$sqli  = mysqli_query($this->cxn->connect(),$query))
    {
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Request");
    }
    else
    {
        if ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)) 
        {
            return $data;
        } 
        else
        {
            return null;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use this? Do you still get a warning about the undefined variable?

Comment: my problem is solved thanks for trying help me. it happend because i was setting my data after i load the view.